# Integral involving the Pochhammer symbol

Tags: integration, pochhammer-symbol

I am wondering do we know any integral idenitiies involving the Pochhammaer symbol? More specficically, if $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbole, do we know any functions f and g make the following the identity true
$$\int_X(x)_nf(x) =g(x)?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, $(x)_n$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are Stirling numbers.

Comment: Thanks. It answered my question perfectly.

Comment: Hey Maxim, do you have any idea about this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203040/integration-involving-x-at-the-power-and-the-gamma-function ?

Comment: You might find Eq:11 of http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/~gvm/radovi/AP-JIS2.pdf useful.

Comment: Many thanks for this paper, rrogers. Exactly the thing I am looking for. This paper is later publised as "2008A Note about the Pochhammer Symbol" on Mathematica Moravica.